# Is it possible to effectively make theme customizer sections sortable and keep the order after save?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

We do have kirki(a theme customizer toolkit) `sortable field`. But i want to apply the same logic on the sections itself instead of creating another section with sortable fields.
 I'm using options instead of theme mods, just for better visualization right now.
 The things i tried so far:
 in `functions.php` I have this code below to create an option row in option table:

```
$sortable_sections = get_option('sortable_sections');
  if(!isset($sortable_sections) OR empty($sortable_sections)){
  add_option('sortable_sections', array('eat', 'pray','love'));
}
```

The code to create sections in a file named `kirki-config.php` which is required in `functions.php` as below

```
$sortable_sections = get_option('sortable_sections');
foreach($sortable_sections as $sortable_section){
 Kirki::add_section( $sortable_section, array(
    'title'          => esc_attr__( strtoupper($sortable_section), 'airspace' ),
    'description'    => esc_attr__( 'Insert content', 'airspace' ),
    'panel'          => 'frontpage_panel',
) );
}
```

the above code creates three sections with id eat, pray, love respectively.

the code in `js` is as below:(file hooked to `admin_enqueue_scripts`)

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

  $('#sub-accordion-panel-frontpage_panel').sortable({
    items: '.control-section-kirki-default',
    axis : 'y',
    cursor: 'move,
   update: function(){
      //here i want the code which gets the updated reordered array and passed to a  
      //php file using .sortable('serialize'), only after clicking the publish
     // button. the problem is the publish button is disabled even after
    // sections got new positions.
   }
  });
});
```

and in php file i want code something like as below:

```
$new_array = $_POST['accordion-section'];
update_option('sortable_sections', $new_array);
```

So there are two steps which i'm having problem to finish.
1. enabling and disabling the publish button
2.after clicking the button js variable goes to php file and updates the option.

How to achieve it, and is there any better method to achieve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I would getting your data when Publish is clicked.

```
(function($) {
  $("#sub-accordion-panel-frontpage_panel").sortable({
    items: "> .control-section-kirki-default",
    axis : "y",
    cursor: "move"
  });
  $("#publish").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var panelOrder = $("#sub-accordion-panel-frontpage_panel").sortable("serialize");
    // Submit data to PHP
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Since you have not provided an MCVE, this is about all I can suggest.

**Update**

```
$("#sub-accordion-panel-frontpage_panel").sortable({
  items: "> .control-section-kirki-default",
  axis : "y",
  cursor: "move",
  update: function(){
    $(this).trigger("change");
  }
});
```

Comment: the problem is that publish button stays deactivated, and only gets activated when values of a control changes, as you see I'm working on sections only and not the controls attached with it, so publish button stays deactivated even when order of section changes. that's how wordpress works unfortunately. Ajax works to update the database, but to maintain the natural process i want to  1. activate publish button upon sections positions changes  2. upon clicking database updates, page refreshes and then the button gets deactivated again and the sections get the new order. I hope i explained it.

Comment: If it is looking for a `change` event, you can trigger one in `update`.

Comment: yeah i can use the change event, but i don't know how to activate and deactivate wordpress theme customizer publish button. Wordpress uses its own internal mechanics to handle it, i'm not sure how to do it. .hide() and .show() not going to work

Comment: *Wordpress uses its own internal mechanics* WP will use either PHP or JavaScript. Since the activity you're describing is Client-Side, this suggests JavaScript. Also look here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/153080/changes-in-widget-customizer-not-triggering-save-and-publish